# Webkit browser display problems

Tags: css, webkit, browser-support

I finally finished my website and low and behold, there are some inconsistencies in webkit based browsers.

[My site](http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/) has issues with certain link images on hover... the Southern University logo near the bottom of the art page, the hotmail, myspace and facebook links on the contact page, and only the images in the "Drawings/Paintings" vertical scrollable move when hovered over (yet all other images don't move on hover, including the images in the other vertical scrollables on the art page).

What could be the cause of this? I'm thinking some kind of CSS deal with webkit, but I'm not totally sure.

Thanks in advance,
Aaron Chauvin

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm testing in Windows Vista Home prem. and Windows 7 Home prem. with the latest builds of Chrome and Safari

Comment: Doesn't move on hover for me... (Chrome + Safari, latest build, mac)

Comment: I have to say that I very much dislike the colours. They make the text difficult to read.

Comment: Maybe on your monitor, I love the color scheme and everyone that I've spoken to personally agreed and liked the contrast between the text and background...

Comment: I'm looking at it with a properly calibrated HP LP2475w (a reasonably good monitor), and it's slightly unpleasant to read the text. Regarding your actual problem: I can't reproduce it with Windows 7 and the latest Chrome stable version *or* the latest Chrome dev version.

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific issues are.  I'm on Safari Mac and not entirely certain what I'm supposed to be seeing here.  I also agree with thirtydot.  It seems like an incredibly dark scheme without enough bright contrast and the text is way too small, IMHO.  With a background that dark, white text is really the only option and would make a large improvement.  BTW- after 12 years of web design, rarely are my friends & colleagues brutally honest enough to criticize even my worst design choices.

Comment: That's wierd, because I'm testing it on two different versions of windows with the latest builds of Chrome and Safari and the images specified are shifting positions on hover... maybe the contrast issue is because you're in a different color space? You're not in the USA, correct?

Comment: Well, neither myself nor anyone in the US that has viewed my site has complained about the contrast between the text and background, but I'll look into lightening the text. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Correct; I'm in England. For what it's worth, I agree with @Sparky672's suggestion for white text - it looks much better.

Comment: I'm on a Sceptre X240BV-FHD and the colors are amazing. I'm sitting about 3-4 feet away and can still read the text just fine. I'll look into lightening the text and maybe enlarging it.

Comment: @Aaron:  I'm near Chicago.  I have color calibrated Samsung monitors.  I do not wear glasses and my vision was last tested at better than 20/200 (top of the scale).  At 1920 x 1200 pixels, I simply think your text is too small for your choice of colors.

Comment: @Aaron:  How does it matter to this issue that @thirtydot is not in the US?

Comment: @Sparky672: I hope you mean 20/20 vision. 20/200 means terrible vision :)

Comment: @thirtydot:  lol... oops... yes, mine is on the other end of the scale.  I was able to read the smallest line on the chart... maybe it was 20 over a fraction like 1/200... the optometrist gave it to me verbally so I didn't visualize it properly.  :D

Comment: @Sparky672 Aren't there differences in hardware (such as display modes/color spaces for graphics cards) in other countries? That's what I thought might be affecting thirtydot's view of the text on my site…

Comment: @Aaron:  I could be wrong here since I'm not a hardware guy but calibrated sRGB is calibrated sRGB no matter where you are... that's the whole point of having calibrated color spaces.

Comment: @thirtydot @Sparky672: I've updated my site with you guys in mind... take a gander.

Comment: It looks mostly the same. The text seems to look improved, so that's good.

Comment: @thirtydot: Did you not see the text options slide-out pane at the top left of each page? It lets you change the text size and even color ('cuz y'all said white would look better).

Comment: @Aaron Chauvin: Nope, I didn't spot that. Probably because I wasn't looking for it, I was just looking at the text (..on a different [worse] monitor, hence the improvement). Allowing the user to set the colour is a good compromise, I guess.

Comment: @thirtydot: Are you experiencing problems with the text size preferences being saved? I'm gettin' some shafty cookie performance with the current plugin implemented (fontscale), if others are experiencing problems with the font size preferences being saved, I'm going to have to switch out the plugin for something else that works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in the provided CSS directory are you using .SU:hover, are you using javascript for the hover or css?

You can simply add something like:

```
.SU link:hover { //change image }
```

Comment: No, I don't want the image to change on hover, I simply don't want the image to move or shift position on hover. It behaves correctly in IE9/FF4, but not in webkit based browsers.

Comment: @Aaron:  Safari Mac is also a Webkit browser.  Nothing is shifting position here.